# Polymorphism and overloaded functions with different signatures

Tags: c++, class, templates, polymorphism

What I want to do : a simple storage class, defined as a template to be as general as possible. And being able to derive from this class another, that would accept anything, convert it to `int` (the algorithm is not relevant here), and store it in the underlying class.

But, this doesn't quite work as expected. Here is the minimal test case I wrote:

```
template<typename T>
class A {
  public:
    void f(T& foo) { }
};

class B : public A<int> {
  public:
    template<typename T>
    void f(T& foo) { }
};

int main() {
  A<int>* ptr = new B;
  ptr->f("foo");
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, this doesn't work:

```
pierre@raringbeast:~/Workspace/Test/src$ icpc -o Test Test.cpp 
Test.cpp(16): error: a reference of type "int &" (not const-qualified) cannot
be initialized with a value of type "const char [4]"
    ptr->f("foo");
           ^

compilation aborted for Test.cpp (code 2)
```

Is there any way to force the compiler to use the method definition from the B class, or is this a *really* bad idea?

--

**Edit**: Made the inheritance public.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, as @GermanDiago pointed out, you're using private inheritance, so you're getting the "base class inaccessible" error. Change `B` to derive from `A<int>` publically.

Even so, this won't fix the issue. Name lookup is based on static types. When you have a pointer to `A<int>`, accessing members through that pointer will only look at the members of `A<int>`.

You have to access through type `B` to see `B`'s members:

```
int main() {
  B* ptr = new B;
  ptr->f("foo");
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

---

Of course, if I understand your question correctly, this is not what you really want. You might look at the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) instead.

```
template <class T, class Derived>
class A {
  public:
    template <class U>
    void f(U& bar) {
      static_cast<Derived*>(this)->f(bar);
    }

    void f(T& foo) {

    }
};


class B : public A<int, B>
{
  public:
    template <class T>
    void f(T &foo) {
      //will be called from A's f(U&)
    }
};


int main() {
  A<int, B>* ptr = new B;
  ptr->f("foo");
  delete ptr;
  return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/80khRh)

Of course, this has the downside of `B` becoming part of `A`'s type. I don't think there's a way out of this while still remaining compile-time.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. Obviously, I'll have to think a little more...

Answer (score 1):

You must use public inheritance:

```
class B : public A<int> {
    //...
}
```

is-a relationship in c++ is through public inheritance. Private inheritance is what you are currently using.

Comment: True, but this will still not allow calling `B::f` through a pointer to `A`.

Comment: Thanks. Simple mistake, that I just corrected. Still doesn't fixes the main issue :/